# Catalogue of images as a chapter

Tags: floats, captions

I would like to insert an appendix in my thesis as a catalog of images.

Something like this [image: this]. I have 30 pages like this.

The code is

```latex
\documentclass[
    crop=false,
    a4paper,
    class=book,
]{standalone}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}

\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{c}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\thefigure}
\makeatother

\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\figurename}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{img/Apparizioni.jpeg}}
{\caption{\textsc{Apparizioni}, 1958 ($60 \times 85$ cm) olio su tela olona}\label{fig:apparizioni}}
\end{SCfigure}

...
\end{document}
```

This works in standalone, however, whenever I try to input in a book class, it will give me deadlock error, since there are of course too many float objects.

Any idea on how should I do this?

I want a simple (long) list of images with their caption on the right-hand side.
Maybe a long table of images is the right solution?

Comment: There is no need to use figure environments, especially since you don't want your images to change position. You can instead use captionof from the caption package instead of the original caption command and drop the figure environments. To place image and caption side by side, you could use minipages.

Comment: Thank you! it was just so simple! I got stucked =D